# How can i set "FILES_ROOT" to a folder on server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-manager, roxy-fileman

I want to use RoxyFileMan to manage uploaded images and files. But I should save them on the server. As you know, RoxyFileMan Upload uploads files and images in a folder named `Uploads` in a fileman directory. We can change `FILES_ROOT` to another local path to change the directory files get uploaded to.

But, I want to upload files on the server and then read them from the server after they've been uploaded so that they can be edited in ckeditor.

Can anyone please provide advice/guidance on how to achive this outcome?

Comment: Please a MVCE that contains code similar to what you've tried to solve your problem so that others have a better understanding of how to help answer your question.

Comment: Grammatical and formatting changes to improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear how your question is meant, but if I understand you correctly, you are using RoxyFileMan on a local server and want to upload files to a remote online server, right?

**Roxy uploads** files to a directory **on the server it is run from**. Which means if run from localhost, it will use directory on your localhost. If run from a server, it will use a directory on server.

As far as my knowledge goes, **you cannot upload from a localhost to an online server directly.**

You could maybe achieve that using some custom script to open an FTP connection, but then you would have to also remake all the code to also load images from there... which would be rather silly.